# Is the word “overwhelming” a positive or negative word?

Tags: meaning

I’ve seen the word *overwhelming* being used to describe positive or negative situations, but it seems pretty confusing because I’m not sure about the real meaning or usage of the word, as I’m not a native speaker. How should I use it?

Comment: It's a **Polar** word; i.e, it comes a the end of at least one cline, like _freezing - cold - cool - warm - hot - boiling_; so you can say _absolutely overwhelming_. However, being overwhelmed can be either good or bad, depending on what's whelming whom over. It means, originally, to turn something, or someone, upside down, by some outside force.

Comment: "The football team's offense was overwhelming." Is this good or bad? It depends on which team you're playing for. You may want to clarify what you mean by "positive" or "negative."

Comment: I wonder if *overwhelm* was ever an extreme form of *whelm* ...

Comment: Do you find the dictionary definition too overwhelming? http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/overwhelm?q=overwhelm

Answer (score 3):

It describes the property of something as having an extreme degree.

E.g.,

"The paint's bright color was overwhelming."

A primary property can be assumed,

"The fire was overwhelming."
 (Probably in terms of heat.)

When the property is not specified, it can mean something like "intense."

"The feeling was overwhelming."

When describing a person or event, it can imply physical or emotional exhaustion.

"The event was overwhelming."
"I'm overwhelmed!"

It can be positive, but, in my opinion, it's default mood is negative, unless the speaker clearly indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

If something is "overwhelming", you mean to say that it is overpowering in effect or strength. 
It can be used in both "negative" and "positive" ways in cases where you need an expression for something "extreme".